# C# null base-class constructor for XML Serialisation ... that derived classes cannot call?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Not sure if a code example is needed here, but here goes.

In the base class I have:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        // empty constructor for XML serialisation
    }

    public BaseClass(<some parameters>)
    {
        // initialise correctly
        [...]
    }

    // force base classes to implement Xml serialisation
    protected abstract XmlDocument AsXmlDocument();

}
```

Then the derived classes have

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass() : base()
    {
        // null constructor
    }

    public override XmlDocument AsXmlDocument()
    {
        // serialization code
        [...]
    }
}
```

I want to make the null constructor `private` so nothing else can call it.  This is so that the classes are initialised correctly through a non-null constructor.  Meaning, I want them initialised so that there is something to serialise.  Leaving the null constructor `protected`, `internal` or `public` means I lose this guarantee.

But if I make the base-class null constructor `private`, then I cannot have null constructors in the derived classes because the base class null constructor is inaccessible.  I get these error even if I remove "`: base()`" from the derived class' null constructor.  The code fails to compile so I have to accept a non-`private` null-constructor even though I don't want one; it introduces risk into my code-base to do so.

It seems wasteful, inefficient and risky to code up serialization via `[Serializable]` or the interface `ISerializable` in each derived class.  Seems like unnecessary labour that goes against the grain of code-reuse and inheritance.

Probably I am missing something obvious or basic about serialisation here.  But so far have found no answer.

**SUBSEQUENT NOTE**

I want to ensure that derived classes are forced to call the non-null constructor.  There are hundreds of derived classes in the project I'm working on, where there is NOT an explicit pass-through to the base-class non-null constructor.

So where I have

```
public DerivedClass(<some parameters>)
{
    [...]
}
```

this gets compiled as

```
public DerivedClass(<some parameters>) : base()
{
    [...]
}
```

but I want this to be thrown as a compile-time error.

I want to force derivations to be explicitly this, or to throw a compiler error:

```
public DerivedClass(<some parameters>) : base(<some parameters>)
{
    [...]
}
```

It seems that there needs to be a new access modifier for constructors perhaps.

Any advice warmly received...

Comment: This seems to confirm my problem rather than solve it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228216/xml-serialisation-default-constructor)

Comment: Child class constructor should call some base class constructor, there is no way to avoid that. You can force child classes to call "non-null" constructor by making "null" one private, but then parameterless constructor in child class should also call "non-null" in parent class, which as I understand is not what you want.

Comment: Yeah so there is a conflict between XML serialisation, which needs a null constructor, and clean design of inheritance in the case when you don't want a null constructor.  I'd love to see a syntactic solution so that you enforce calling of the right parameterised base-class constructor OR you can have an XML-only constructor that nothing else can call.  It's a loose end in C# that needs tying off.

Comment: Have made a suggestion to the C# language team here     https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/33114760-syntactic-solution-so-derived-class-doesn-t-accide

Answer (score 0):

You should definetly take a look at the **protected** modifier.

If you make a protected Constructor the Constructor can be only called from inheriating classes and :base() will work again.

Comment: I want to block the possibility that derived classes erroneously call the base class null constructor.  I want them to be forced to initialised correctly by only allowing them to call the non-null constructor.  Protected null constructor breaches this requirement.